# Modify Eloquent cast JSON to attributes

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

My Eloquent model has an attribute/column called "group_answers" which is a json representation of additional custom questions and answers, like;

```
{
  "satisfied_with_course":"3",
  "satisfied_with_teacher":"5",
  "satisfied_with_residence":"2", 
}
```

Is it possible to alter the Model so that I have additional attributes for each key? That can be called like `$model->satisfied_with_course` instead of `$model->group_answers['satisfied_with_course']`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Eloquent's Accessor and Mutator options. So for the Mutator you would have something like this in your model.

```
public function setSatisfiedWithCourceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['group_answers']['satisfied_with_course'] = $value;
}
```

And your Accessor would look like this:

```
public function getSatisfiedWithCourceAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->group_answers['satisfied_with_course'];
}
```

I'll try to setup up something so I can test and make sure it works.

Here is the documentation for the Accessors and Mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Ah, so I'd have to know what the questions were in order to create an Mutator/Accessor methods on the Model?? I suppose that's fine actually.

Comment: You could use the PHP magic getters and setters option, however not necessarily recommended.